# Plotly marginal histogram stack data instead of displaying different marginal histograms

Tags: python, plot, plotly, histogram, violin-plot

I'm a bit lost with the plotly library.
I want to display a violin histogram close to my data display such as the one in example[image: example]

```
import plotly.express as px
df = px.data.iris()
fig = px.scatter(df, x="sepal_length", y="sepal_width", color="species", 
                 marginal_x="box", marginal_y="violin",
                  title="Click on the legend items!")
fig.show()
```

but when i try to implement it to my data set it stack all the datas together not as the example.[image]
My data set is composed of differents data such as particule number, mass, position X,Y,Z, speed, etc...
can you help me to find the problem ?

I tryed

```
d = {'nbr':number,'mass': mass,'charge': charge, 'x': x, 'y': y,'z': z,'speed':speed,'azm':azm,'elv':elv, 'energie_cinetique':energie_cinetique }
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
figuredistrib=px.scatter(df,x='x',y='z', color= 'charge', marginal_x="violin",marginal_y="violin")
figuredistrib.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

The difference is because the Plotly example is reading the categories as strings rather then numbers. The solution is to simply change the 'charge' column to strings.

Also, in the future please include sample data.

```
#creating a sample database
df = pd.DataFrame({'x':[random.uniform(125, 175) for n in range(500)]+[random.uniform(145, 165) for n in range(500)],
           'z':[random.uniform(245, 255) for n in range(250)]+[random.uniform(270, 280) for n in range(250)]+[random.uniform(280, 285) for n in range(250)]+[random.uniform(290, 310) for n in range(250)],
           'charge':[12]*250+[11]*250+[10]*500})

figuredistrib=px.scatter(df,x='x',y='z', color= 'charge', marginal_x="violin",marginal_y="violin")

figuredistrib.show()
```

[image: Fig 1]

The fix

```
df['charge'] = df['charge'].astype(str)

figuredistrib=px.scatter(df,x='x',y='z', color= 'charge', marginal_x="violin",marginal_y="violin")

figuredistrib.show()
```

[image: Fig 2]